# Is Enlightment the destiny of every soul?

Tags: atma, moksha, enlightenment, destiny

Is every soul bound to be liberated eventually? Does the timing depend on the soul, or divine intervention?

Comment: Destionation of every Jiva is to return to source. How long depends on each jeeva which is based on minds desires and satisifcation of worldly life.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no specific achievement for the souls stated anywhere in the Hindu scripture which all the souls are supposed to attain. As far as I know there is no statement anywhere in the scripture which says something like "Everyone will become enlightened and will get liberated, ie get moksha eventually". Enlightenment and ultimately moksha may happen or may not happen to the soul. It's not that it must happen for everyone. It will happen to the soul who deserves it, that's for sure.

Comment: Basic thing I don't get about the concept is, if there is liberation that broth /death cycle is broken, but then why was there any birth death to begin with, if the goal is just to break free from it,.. But then if the soul is not liberated, does it just go through birth death through eternity?

Comment: If a soul doesn't get enlightened he will never get moksha and thus he will continue with samsara, ie repeated births and deaths forever, until he gets enlightened and liberated. Samsara, ie repeated births and deaths happen to the soul because of his ignorance. When ignorance is removed and enlightenment is achieved, a soul gets liberated, ie gets moksha and there is no more samsara for that soul.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa - there is one explicit statement in prabandham about moksha being the destiny of any jiva. but there are different interpretations to it as well.

Comment: @ram Well, that may be so, however Prabandham is a literature of authority only for Sri Vaishnavas or followers of Ramanuja but not generally for all Hindus. In my comment above what I meant by "Hindu scripture" was scriptures which are not sampradaya specific, namely scriptures such as Upanishads, Gita, Puranas, Itihasas, Pancaratras, etc.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa - all scriptures written by azhwars, commentaries of 3 acharyas, 'translations' of itihasa/puranas like Tulsidas or Kamban - are generally accepted as 'Hindu' scripture. For e.g. Brahma/Vaivarta-puranas might be one of the 18, but not accepted as Satvika purana. So, one sect might quote it, another might not. Scripture cannot be isolated from its Bhashya. Because we get to know scripture, only through bhashya. It's like saying dictionary is not as important as shakespeare. we can understand shakespeare only with dictionary.

Comment: @ram Yes, that's true. All those scriptures deserve to be called as "Hindu". No doubt about that. On the other hand, I was talking about Hindu teachings in a more general way, not just sampradaya specific.

Answer (score 1):

For evil persons Their destination is andhamas that is their true aspect or attribute. The whole creation is meant to realize once true state. From BG. 16.19-20 Its  clear that moksha is not for evil persons.

तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |
क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु || 19||
आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा जन्मनि जन्मनि |
मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || 20||

tān ahaṁ dviṣhataḥ krūrān sansāreṣhu narādhamān
kṣhipāmy ajasram aśhubhān āsurīṣhv eva yoniṣhu
āsurīṁ yonim āpannā mūḍhā janmani janmani
mām aprāpyaiva kaunteya tato yānty adhamāṁ gatim

BG 16.19-20: These cruel and hateful persons, the vile and vicious of humankind, I constantly hurl into the wombs of those with similar demoniac natures in the cycle of rebirth in the material world. These ignorant souls take birth again and again in demoniac wombs. Failing to reach me, O Arjun, they gradually sink to the most abominable type of existence.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not the destiny it is the necessity of every soul. Without knowing who we are or the self before death arrives is like living a dream.
And in a dream we never know we are in a dream first, and where we will wake up
after the dream second.

Calling enlightenment destiny creates an illusionary thought, that it will happen automatically, eventually since its a destiny, destiny means it will happen for sure.
But it is not like that, to attain enlightenment one has to seek it, practice it.

every human has two options, to live the life with nature like any other animals do OR to rise above the nature, this possibility is true for humans only. So, its not a matter of time its a matter of doing it.

After enlightenment you will know, you are in a dream, and where will you wake up, what else is needed in this life? You know everything then.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Please do so. To learn more visit help section of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on how one interprets the following Gita verses.

> These vicious men, oppressive, cruel and sinful as they are, -- are
> always hurled by Me into demoniac wombs in life after life, in the
> transmigratory cycle.

**Gita 16.19**

> O son of Kunti! Falling into demoniac wombs, **in life after life, they
> go to still lower states of degradation, without attaining Me**.

**Gita 16.20**

> On the basis of such texts, some schools of Vedanta like those of Sri
> Madhva and Sri Vallabha have propounded the theory of *taratamya* or
> inherent qualitative differences in Jivas, some being made for
> salvation and others for degradation. There is no eternal damnation in
> Hinduism, but this confinement to '*adhamam gatim*' or continued
> embodiments among the lowest creatures like insects, fish, snakes
> etc,. corresponds to it as the wages for confirmed evil doers.
>
> There is a theoretical possibility of salvation even for such degraded
> souls when Divine grace descends on them through Incarnations and
> through very holy saints. Since Samsara or the transmigratory cycle is
> a never-ending process, perpetual involvement in it is the attaining
> to that most heinous destiny - *yant yadhamam gatim*.

**Srimad Bhagavad Gita commentary of Gita 16.19-20 by Swami Tapasyananda**

Most other sects do not interpret these Gita texts so literally and say that everyone would get liberation, some early and some very late.

Comment: This were Swami Tapasyananda adds his own interpretation of scripture based on his head instead of what krishna says.. "Mamappraiva"   for him the exact rule will be applied because he misinterrupted Sri krishnas word

Comment: Tapasyananda actually is stating the position of Ramakrishna who said that everyone will attain enlightenment some early and some late.